# A word for speaking for an animal?

Tags: word-choice

You know that Disney movie Frozen? Remember the part where Kristoff is alone with his elk or reindeer and he is speaking for it in order with have a conversation with himself?

Is there a word for doing that? For speaking out loud for your pet?

Not necessarily attributing human characteristics but actually speaking for your pet.

Cause I do it all the time for my Bassett Hound mix.

Yes, I'm single and live alone and don't have any friends.

Comment: Not an answer, but this made me think of "rubber-ducking", where you explain a problem (e.g. in programming) to a real or imaginary rubber duck (or to a colleague, who has no insight in the problem)

Comment: I wouldn't worry until the basset talks back.  Then you both might consider couples therapy.

Comment: St David (of Wales) used to send messages to distant friends by going to the seashore and talking to the seals He solved a tricky problem with a cook with the answers he got back, Rhygyfarch's Life of David.

Comment: Not a spot-on but I once (perhaps incorrectly) used *ventriloquise* when describing a kid playing his toys and voicing their conversation.

Comment: Then I'll make it an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is mainly used for describing the performance of ventriloquism, I used (perhaps incorrectly) *ventriloquize* to something like what you're asking.

> ventriloquize: to speak or sound in the manner of a ventriloquist [[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ventriloquise)]

I used the word to describe a boy playing his toys and voicing them(like what Andy did in those Toy Story movies). I am not sure whether it's acceptable to use it in such figurative sense, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have ruled out "**anthropomorphizing**" by writing, "Not necessarily attributing human characteristics," I don't believe there is a single term in English for what you describe.

Comment: Right, the term ***is*** *anthropomorphising*